# How to build a histogram from the mean of 100 matrices

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, random, histograms, sparse-arrays

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
    n1 = 5;
    f[i_, j_] :=  With[{z := RandomInteger[j - 1]},If[i != j, RandomChoice[{z/n1, 1 - z/n1} -> {1, 0}], 0]];
    s = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n1, n1}];
```

I want to generate a list of 100 matrices that looks like this:

```
n2 = 100;
s1 = Table[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n1, n1}], {k, n2}];
```

Now I want to build two histograms from the average of n2-matrices:

i) the frequency numbers one per line;

ii) the frequency numbers 1 per column.

From the distribution would get the kurtosis and skewness.

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't quite understand your points i) and ii). Could you be more specific? Maybe show an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: a bit aside to your question but the delayed set `z:=` causes the two `z` instances in `RandomChoice` to have different values. Probably you want a non-delayed `z=`

Comment: is this what you want for `i` ? `Histogram[Mean[Flatten@#] & /@ s1]`

Comment: The command `s1 = Table[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n1, n1}], {k, n2}];`  generates 100 matrices 5x5 . The elements of each matrix are 0 or 1. I would like to build a histogram of the frequency numbers 1 obtained in each row and each column.

Comment: What are "frequency numbers 1"? How many times the number 1 occurs in each of the five rows?

Comment: Yes, corey979. This is it.

Comment: Is my answer below what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what is expected, so let it be for a start.

To get the mean of the matrices `s1`:

```
mean = Normal @ Mean @ s1;
MatrixForm @ mean
```

[image]

One can visualize the matrix with `MatrixPlot`:

```
MatrixPlot[mean, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

To get the row-wise histogram:

```
rowSum = Total /@ Total /@ Transpose@s1
```

> {92, 82, 78, 63, 63}

```
Plot[Piecewise@
  Table[{rowSum[[i]], i - 0.5 < x < i + 0.5}, {i, 1, 
    Length@rowSum}], {x, 0.5, 5.5}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}}, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Row number i", "Count of 1"}]
```

[image]

Because columns are rows of a transposed matrix, let's just transpose each of them in the list `s1` and proceed like previously:

```
sT = Transpose /@ s1;
colSum = Total /@ Total /@ Transpose@sT
```

> {0, 46, 74, 106, 152}

```
Plot[Piecewise@
  Table[{colSum[[i]], i - 0.5 < x < i + 0.5}, {i, 1, 
    Length@colSum}], {x, 0.5, 5.5}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}}, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Column number i", "Count of 1"}]
```

[image]